# How to correct Android Activity's Layout elements stacking over each other?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem in the layout of my app's activity. 
 The top elements (text-views, edit text boxes) are coming jumbled up. 

There is some sort of overlapping between elements though XML Layout's code looks fine (a similarly designed code is in use by another activity and is working fine).
Here is a ScreenShot (notice the overlapping of elements near top): 
[image]

My XML Layout's code:(for reference)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_main_border"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:context=".Ques1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_outlet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="@string/name_outlet"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_outlet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView_outlet"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView_outlet"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,&apos;1234567890 "
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_outlet"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_owner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view1"
                android:text="@string/name_owner"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_owner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_owner"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_owner"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.&apos; "
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_owner"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_phonenos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view2"
                android:text="@string/phone_nos"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_phonenos"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="3"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1_phonenos"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="3"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos3"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1_phonenos2"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="3"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1_phonenos3"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="3"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_phonenos4"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_state"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view3"
                android:text="@string/name_state"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_state"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_state"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_state"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.&apos; "
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_state"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view4"
                android:text="@string/name_city"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_city"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_city"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. "
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_city"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_market"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view5"
                android:text="@string/market"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_market"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_market"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_market"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,&apos;1234567890 "
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_market"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_gps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view6"
                android:text="@string/gps_coord"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_gps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_gps"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_gps"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_gps"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_outlet_pic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view7"
                android:text="@string/pic_outlet"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01_outletpic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_outlet_pic"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/select_pic"
                android:text="@string/selectPic_btn"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Button01_outletpic"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_quad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view8"
                android:text="@string/quad_code"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1_quad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_quad"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_quad"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/editText1_quad"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_own_veh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view9"
                android:text="@string/own_veh"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_own_veh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1_own_veh"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/radio0_yes"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio0"
                    android:text="@string/radio1_no"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup1_own_veh"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_own_sales_team"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view10"
                android:text="@string/own_sales_team"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_own_salesT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1_own_sales_team"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio011"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/radio011_yes"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio022"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio011"
                    android:text="@string/radio022_no"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup1_own_salesT"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_own_goods_collect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view11"
                android:text="@string/own_goods_collect"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_own_goods_coll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1_own_goods_collect"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio033"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/radio033_yes"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio044"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio033"
                    android:text="@string/radio044_no"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup1_own_goods_coll"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_monthly_vOl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view12"
                android:text="@string/monthly_vOl"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1_monthly_vOl"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/cat1"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat1"
                android:text="@string/cat2"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cbCat1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/cat3"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat3"
                android:text="@string/cat4"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cbCat3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/cat5"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/cbCat5"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_monthly_vAl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view13"
                android:text="@string/monthly_vAl"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1_monthly_vAl"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/cat11"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat11"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat11"
                android:text="@string/cat22"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cbCat11"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/cat33"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat44"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat33"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat33"
                android:text="@string/cat44"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCat55"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cbCat33"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/cat55"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/cbCat55"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewMenuBarP1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/view14"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNxtPage2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/viewMenuBarP1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/btnNextPage2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any advice is appreciable..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView_outlet" and not android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_outlet"

@+id is to create a new id whereas @id is used when the id has already been created.

Please feel free to ask any doubts if the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Don't define `toRightOf` only, but `toLeftOf`, `above` and `below` too when needed.

Comment: Thx for replying fast..IMO I have already defined not only `toRightOf` but also `below` tag. Can you possibly see  a conflict somewhere in my code? As I see..the stacking up of elements is only present in the top 3-4 elements only..the rest below them appear fine.

Comment: The problem is your first `View` widget, is not positioning where you expect.

Comment: I tried changing `android:layout_below="@id/editText1_outlet"` tag of `view` to `android:layout_below="@id/textView_outlet"` That din't helped either. I guess due to the tags `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` OR
                `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` defined in `@+id/textView_outlet` or `@+id/editText1_outlet` are being problematic for the first view i.e. `view1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
   <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <ScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:fillViewport="true" >
            <RelativeLayout
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               app:context=".Ques1" >
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_outlet"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:text="name_outlet"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
           <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/editText1_outlet"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView_outlet"                                                                         
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView_outlet"
                 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,&apos;1234567890 "
                  android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                  android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
     android:id="@+id/view1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
     android:layout_below="@id/editText1_outlet"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dp" />

     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1_owner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/view1"
      android:text="name_owner"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

       <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText1_owner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1_owner"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_owner"
      android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.&apos; "
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:textSize="12sp" />

  <View
     android:id="@+id/view2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_owner"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText1_phonenos4"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
     android:paddingBottom="2dp"
   android:paddingTop="2dp" />

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1_state"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
   android:text="name_state"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText1_state"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"                          
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1_state"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_state"
   android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.&apos; "
   android:ems="10"
   android:inputType="textPersonName"
   android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
       android:id="@+id/view4"                                                                                                                                      
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                    
      android:layout_height="2dp"                                                                                                                                      
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"                                                                                                                                      
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_state"                                                                                                                                      
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"                                                                                                                                      
       android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"                                                                                                                                     
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"                                                                                                                                     
      android:paddingTop="10dp" />
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                   
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                      
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/view2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       android:text="phone_nos"                                                                                                                                     
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />                                                                                                                                     

   <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                   
     android:layout_width="45dp"                                                                                                                                       
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                       
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                       
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                       
     android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"                                                                                                                                       
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                       
     android:digits="0123456789"                                                                                                                                     
     android:ems="3"                                                                                                                                       
    android:inputType="phone"                                                                                                                                        
     android:maxLength="3"                                                                                                                                       
     android:textSize="12sp" />                                                                                                                                       
   <EditText                                                                                                                                            
     android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos2"
     android:layout_width="45dp"                                                                              
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                       
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                     
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                      
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                     
       android:ems="3"                                                                                                                                     
      android:inputType="phone"                                                                                                                                     
       android:maxLength="5"                                                                                                                                     
       android:textSize="12sp" />                                                                                                                                     
          <EditText                                                                                                                                   
          android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos3"
           android:layout_width="50dp"                                                                                                                             
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                   
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1_phonenos"                                                                                                                                 
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1_phonenos2"                                                                                                                                 
              android:digits="0123456789"                                                                                                                               
            android:ems="3"                                                                                                                                 
            android:inputType="phone"                                                                                                                               
            android:maxLength="5"     
       android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText                                                                             
    android:id="@+id/editText1_phonenos4                                       
    android:layout_width="60dp"                                                                                                                                        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                                                                                        
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1_phonenos3"                                                                                                                                        
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1_phonenos3"                                                                                                                                        
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1_phonenos3"                                                                                                                                        
    android:digits="0123456789"                                                                                                                                        
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:maxLength="5"
   android:textSize="12sp" />
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1_city"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/view4"
    android:text="name_city"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <EditText                                                                                                                                    
     android:id="@+id/editText1_city"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1_city"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_city"
     android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. "
     android:ems="10"
     android:inputType="textPersonName"
     android:textSize="12sp" />
  <View
  android:id="@+id/view5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_city"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp" />
    <TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1_market"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/view5"
android:text="market"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1_market"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1_market"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_market"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,&apos;1234567890 "
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textSize="12sp" />
<View
android:id="@+id/view6"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_market"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1_gps"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/view6"
android:text="gps_coord"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <EditText                                                                                                                                         
android:id="@+id/editText1_gps"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1_gps"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_gps"
android:clickable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:ems="10"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textSize="12sp" />
<View
android:id="@+id/view7"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_gps"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp" />
<TextView                                                                                                                                            
android:id="@+id/textView1_outlet_pic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/view7"
android:text="pic_outlet"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<View
android:id="@+id/view8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_outlet_pic"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1_quad"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/view8"
android:text="quad_code"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<Button                                                                                                                                          
android:id="@+id/Button01_outletpic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1_outlet_pic"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_state"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/select_pic"
android:text="selectPic_btn"
android:textSize="10sp" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1_quad"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1_quad"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1_quad"                                                                                                                                               
android:clickable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:ems="10"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textSize="12sp" />
<View                                                                                                                                      
android:id="@+id/view9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_quad"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>
                                                                                                                                       android:paddingTop="2dp" 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_own_veh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view9"
            android:text="own_veh"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_own_veh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_own_veh"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="radio0_yes"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radio0"
                android:text="radio1_no"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1_own_veh"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_own_sales_team"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view10"
            android:text="own_sales_team"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_own_salesT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_own_sales_team"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio011"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="radio011_yes"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio022"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radio011"
                android:text="radio022_no"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1_own_salesT"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_own_goods_collect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view11"
            android:text="own_goods_collect"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1_own_goods_coll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_own_goods_collect"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio033"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="radio033_yes"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio044"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radio033"
                android:text="radio044_no"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1_own_goods_coll"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_monthly_vOl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/view12"
            android:text="@string/monthly_vOl"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1_monthly_vOl"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cat1"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat1"
            android:text="@string/cat2"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cbCat1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cat3"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat3"
            android:text="@string/cat4"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cbCat3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cat5"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Comment: Hi, this is incomplete code..Can you please post a full edited code of mine?

Comment: hi i could complete your code for your design that code worked for me if u need this use it i split the code into two answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code continue to be here:

```
              <View
            android:id="@+id/view13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cbCat5"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_monthly_vAl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/view13"
            android:text="@string/monthly_vAl"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1_monthly_vAl"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cat11"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat11"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat11"
            android:text="@string/cat22"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cbCat11"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cat33"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cbCat33"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbCat33"
            android:text="@string/cat44"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCat55"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cbCat33"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/cat55"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cbCat55"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewMenuBarP1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/view14"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNxtPage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewMenuBarP1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/btnNextPage2" />            
        </RelativeLayout>                
       </ScrollView>   
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx..I already solved the issue. Still, thanks a ton for helping me out.